# Describe the kernel and the fibers of $\phi$ geometrically (as subsets of the plane).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Define $\phi : \mathbb{C}^{\times} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ by $\phi(a+bi) = a^2 + b^2$. Prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism and find the image of $\phi$. Describe the kernel and the fibers of $\phi$ geometrically (as subsets of the plane).

**Part One**

Proving that it is a homomorphism is trivial and I did it correctly. I was hoping to receive a review of the other three parts.

The image of $\phi$ is the set of all positive real numbers. (*Not sure how to "prove" this as it seems rather trivial. Should I maybe do a proof by contradiction, or is it trivial enough to state without proof?*)

**Part Two**

We define the kernel of $\phi$ as $\{g \in G\mid \phi(g) = 1\}$.

If $\phi(g) = 1$, then $1 = a^2 +b^2$. Obviously, this means either $a^2 =1$ or $b^2=1$, i.e. $a=1, a=-1, b=1,$ or $b=-1$. Note that this implies that the kernel of $\phi = \{\pm1,\pm i\}$.

(*Particularly concerned about the next part*)

For any value $\phi(x) = c^2$, for any $x\in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$, $x$ can be of the form $\pm c+0i$ or $0\pm ci$. From this we can generalize, since addition is commutative that $\forall a^2+b^2 \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$.

$X_{a^2+b^2} = \{\pm a \pm bi, \pm b \pm ai\}$

My main concern is my lack of detail. I would really appreciate advice on how to flesh out my proof.

Comment: Why do you consider only elements $a + bi$ with $a$ and $b$ integers? Without that restriction, the kernel is just the unit circle; and the fibers are exactly the circles centered around 0.

Comment: By definition, $\mathbb{C} = \{a+bi| a,b, \in \mathbb{R}, i^2 = -1\}$.

$\mathbb{C}^x = \mathbb{C} -{0}$

Comment: Right, so the $a$ and $b$ come from ${\mathbb R}$, not from ${\mathbb Z}$. So, for instance, the kernel doesn't just contain $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$, but also all (other) $a + bi$ with $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

Comment: Would it help you to rewrite $\phi(z) = |z|^2$?

Comment: But does that mean that the fibers form circles in the complex plane?
For example, in describing the kernel, we have the set $\{a+bi | a^2+b^2=1\}$. Doesn't this suggest that the set of $a$'s and $b$'s come from the unit circle and determine a set, not that the set is itself the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, that's the kernel - and that set itself is the unit circle (in the complex plane). Not the $a$'s and $b$'s: they come from $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the necro-answer; there was a necro-edit, and there was no answer, so it seems justified to put in an answer for completeness.

The image is the positive reals. The map is a homomorphism of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{C}^*$ into the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{R}^*$. This comes from the identity $|zw|=|z||w|$ for complex numbers $z,w$, which can be proven in a number of algebraic ways.

So the fibers are the points which map to a given positive real number $r$; these are circles of radius $\sqrt{r}$. The kernel is the fiber of $1$ (since the identity in the image space is the *multiplicative* identity, namely $1$), which is the unit circle.